# next available row & transposing

Tags: excel, vba, row, transpose

I have data on one worksheet in C7:C18.  This data needs to copied to the next available row on a different worksheet.  I have been on this for hours and I just cant get it to work.

I have managed to get the transpose part to work but in constantly overwrites the same row.

```
    Private Sub SaveCust()
    Dim NRow As Long
    Worksheets("CustDB").Select
    NRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("CustDB").Range("a" & NRow & ":L"& NRow).Value = 
         WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Customer").Range("c7:c18"))

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a value in C7 ?

Comment: Your code works as it should work. It will copy the range you mentioned on the last empty row. If you will run the code again, it will return on the newly empty row... What do you want against what the code does? Do you show as a part of an iteration and everything rewrite the last row? If yes, you must include the line `NRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` inside the iteration loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub SaveCust()
Dim cus, cdb As Worksheet
Dim NRow As Long

Set cus = Worksheets("Customer")
Set cdb = Worksheets("CustDB")

NRow = cdb.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1


cdb.Range("a" & NRow & ":L" & NRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cus.Range("c7:C18").Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Not sure why but my attempt was just overwriting on the last row of data.